# '!undefined control sequence' and 'missing delimiter'

Tags: equations, symbols

I am using this equation in latex but I get errors of 
'!undefined control sequence' and 
'missing delimiter'

```
\begin{equation}
w_{ij} = exp(-\beta \left \lVert \vec{g}_i - \vec{g}_j \right \rVert^2)
\end{equation}
```

How can I make it fine?

Answer (score 5):

Some suggestions:

- To avoid getting '!undefined control sequence' messages when LaTeX encounters `\lVert` and `\rVert`, be sure to load either the `amsmath` package or the `mathtools` package. (The latter is a superset of the former.)
- Be sure to write `\exp` rather than just `exp`.
- Don't use `\left` and `\right` on `\lVert` and `\rVert`, respectively: In the present case, they don't affect the vertical sizing, but they do mess up the horizontal spacing.
- Optionally, increase the size of the round parentheses via `\bigl` and `\bigr` directives.
- Optionally, use the `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` directive of the `mathtools` package to create a new macro, called `\norm`, which encases its contents in double vertical bars. Writing `\norm{...}` is easier to debug than `\lVert ... \rVert`. It is also more in the spirit of LaTeX, which strongly encourages separating content-related code from code that governs how the content is displayed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\DeclarePairedDelimiter' macro
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm\lVert\rVert
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
w_{ij} = \exp\bigl(-\beta \norm{\vec{g}_i -\vec{g}_j}^2\bigr)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I still get the error below.

Comment: ! Undefined control sequence. w_{ij} = \exp\bigl(-\beta \norm

Comment: @Goli - Do you load the `mathtools` package in the preamble and execute the instruction `\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm\lVert\rVert` (also in the preamble)?

Comment: I use mathtools package as \usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools} in the preamble but I do not use \DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm\lVert\rVert anywhere

Comment: @Goli - The instruction `\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm\lVert\rVert` defines `\norm`. If you don't run `\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm\lVert\rVert` in the preamble, you cannot use `\norm` in the body of the document.

Comment: Thank you I already solved the problem.

Comment: I think the problem was exactly the package! I did not have the package \usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools} before ... Then with the same equation I write in the main question it was run.

Comment: @Mico I'd be more cautious: “*In the present case* they [`\left` and `\right`] don't to anything...”

Comment: @egreg - Many thanks for this observation. I've updated the text of my answer accordingly.